# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2016-03-01' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
alter procedure sp1GetPricesByIteIdUserDateOccupancyNoOfPersons
    --@IteId nvarchar(50),
    @Occupancy nvarchar(50),
    @UserDate varchar(50)
    --@NoOfPersons nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)

    SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT ['+@Occupancy+'] FROM Tbl_ItineraryDetails where '+@UserDate+' between [From Date] and [To Date]'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
END
```

I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2016-03-01' to data type int

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2016-03-01' to data type int.

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely, the problem is the date format in the string `@UserDate`.  You are putting the value in the query string directly and you have no quotes around it.  So, unless it is a column name or contains single quote delimiters, the query is likely to generate an error.

You are using `sp_executesql`, so use parameters.  That is one major reason for using it:

```
alter procedure sp1GetPricesByIteIdUserDateOccupancyNoOfPersons (
    --@IteId nvarchar(50),
    @Occupancy nvarchar(50),
    @UserDate varchar(50)
    --@NoOfPersons nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)

    SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT ['+@Occupancy+'] FROM Tbl_ItineraryDetails where @UserDate between [From Date] and [To Date]';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@UserDate nvarchar(50)', @UserDate = @UserDate;
END;
```

EDIT:

Given the error, you probably want to pass in a date:

```
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@UserDate DATE', @UserDate = @UserDate;
```